# What language (if it is a language) is it?

Tags: orthography

[image]

It looks close to Arabic, but it isn't. I wasn't able to identify which language is it using different scanning tools (including Google Translate app). Thanks.

Edit: if this isn't clear - I'm asking about the silver lettering on the clock's case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The lettering on the frame certainly seems like Arabic script, which means it could be various languages which use this, including Arabic, Persian, and Urdu.  Or even just decorative nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Classical Arabic, the same text is written twice, at the top and at the bottom, both begin on the right side of the clock.

It is the same text which is written of the [flag of Saudi Arabia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Saudi_Arabia).
The text is [Shahada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahada) (“Testimony”), also spelled *Shahadah*, it is an Islamic oath, one of the Five Pillars of Islam and part of the Adhan:

لَا إِلٰهَ إِلَّا الله مُحَمَّدٌ رَسُولُ الله

*Lā ilāha illā -llāh, muḥammadun rasūlu -llāh.*

“There is no god but Allah; Muhammad is the Messenger of Allah”.

Comment: I can read مُحَمَّدٌ رَسُولُ الله at the bottom, but most of the rest looks like gibberish.  I think this is a mixture of Arabic and pseudo-Arabic.

Comment: @fdb - No, it's definitely not pseudo-Arabic, it's just written stretched with the final ہ written open, not closed, like this, only without the Hamza: ـۂ.